# JAVA: How to parse log file till specific line is found like a tail command in linux?

Tags: java

I want to parse the log file till specific line is found in the log file like a tail command.

I am using bufferreader and want to do something like this-

Code-

```
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
       FileReader("/file1.txt"));
       String line;
       boolean keepReading = true;
       while (br.readLine()!= null) {

         line= br.readLine();
         if(line.equals("string found"))
          {
                break;
          }
         else
           {
              //some stuff
           }}
```

I just want to wait for particular string, till then I just want to continue the loop but the condition is, may be the specific string is yet to come and I want to wait for it?

Comment: No, tailing log file using JAVA , what I am asking

Comment: @sanvi: Now that you've significantly modified the behavior of your code, it's time for you to re-test it.  If it still doesn't work as expected, provide more debugging information to replicate the behavior.  (The inputs used, perhaps a link to a hosted runnable example, etc.)  Since you've made a significant modification you've already invalidated existing interactions on this question and the new information may merit asking a new question.

Comment: I fear you are mixing concepts so your question is not clear.  Checking a line for equality against an expected value is pretty trivial.  I think your real concern is "How do I tail a file in Java?".  It is not trivial to do correctly but a little google-fu should provide some good examples.

Comment: yes , i need to tail a file in java @vsdDawg

Answer (score 0):

String comparisons should be done with the `equals(String)` method. Strings are immutable objects, meaning each string is a separate object. The `equals(String)` method compares the content of the strings.

Comment: apart from this, I am asking how to wait for specific line  till it is found like a tail command in linux

Answer (score 0):

In Java you check string equality by :

```java
if(line.equals("string found")){
}
```